# How to recursively call a function until the output is met?

Tags: java, function, arraylist

I have a piece of code that contains two functions `reverse()` that reverses an input list and `rotate()` that puts the last element to the start of the first.

Now I am given another list, in the function `public int minimumOps(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b)` which contains the same elements as the original list but in different order. I am trying to find how many times `reverse()` and/or `rotate()` must be called for the new list to be converted back into the original list. For instance, consider `S = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `T = [2, 1, 4, 3]`, we can see that

```
T = rotate(rotate(reverse(S))) gives us the output
```

But this is not the only way to transform S to T. To illustrate, here are some other sequence of operations:

```
T = reverse(rotate(rotate(S)))
T = rotate(rotate(rotate(reverse(rotate(S)))))
T = reverse(rotate(rotate(reverse(reverse(S))))))
```

Our goal in this problem is to find the smallest number of operations to achieve this transformation.

I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. Here is what I have so far:

```
public int minimumOps(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < a.size(); x++){
                if (Objects.equals(a.get(x), b.get(x))){
                    count += 0;
                }
                else{
                    while(!Objects.equals(a.get(x),b.get(x))){
                        reverse(b);
                        rotate(b);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
        public static List<Integer> rotate(List<Integer> l) {
            List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            li.add(l.get(l.size() - 1));
            for (int i = 0; i < l.size() - 1; i++) {
                li.add(l.get(i));
            }
            return li;
        }

        public static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> l) {
            List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = l.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                li.add(l.get(i));
            }
            return li;
        }
```

Any ideas on how to approach or solve the `minimumOps(a,b)` and find the number of `rotate()` and/or `reverse()` needed to turn list b into list a would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think of any specific algorithm for solving the problem. It may be worth trying heuristic search algorithms, such as IDA*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_A*  The problem is choosing the right heuristic. You can start by determining the "distance" at which a given permutation of the source data is removed from a target sequence. If an item in the list is out of place, then "distance" can be the number of steps it takes to set it in place. The sum of such distances for all elements of the list is the "distance" of the permutation from the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your answer, this will only find the minimum number of transforms:

```java
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var a = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
        var b = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 1, 4, 3));
        var output = minimumOps(a, b);
        if (output == Integer.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("Can't be solved");
        else System.out.println("Min transforms: "+output); 
    }

    /*
        let's draw operations tree, that is, for each list we can either reverse (rev) or rotate (rot)
                              a
                              |
                           /     \
                         rev     rot
                        /   \    /   \
                      rev  rot  rev  rot
                      / \  / \  / \  / \
                       ⋮     ⋮    ⋮     ⋮

        we know that reverse(reverse(list)) == list, so we can prune rev if its parent is rev.

                              a
                              |
                           /     \
                         rev     rot
                          |     /   \
                         rot   rev  rot
                         / \    |   / \
                          ⋮      ⋮    ⋮

       now let's apply this 'blindly'.
    */
    public static int minimumOps(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        if (Objects.equals(a, b)) return 0;

        // minimumOpsRec is a helper method that will be called recursively
        int revCount = minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, 1, OP.REV);
        int rotCount = minimumOpsRec(rotate(a), b, 1, OP.ROT);

        return Math.min(revCount, rotCount);
    }

    // a and b are lists that we are transforming,
    // count is our counter that will be incremented by each transform
    // parentOP is the previous operation from parent, i.e., rev or rot, see enum
    public static int minimumOpsRec(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b, int count, OP parentOP) {
        if (Objects.equals(a, b)) return count; // base condition, return if a == b

        // however not all lists can be sorted using this algorithm, generally speaking,
        // if the output of this method greater than the list size then it's not sortable.
        // for example try to solve this using this algorithm by yourself (hint: you cannot): a = [1, 2, 3, 4], b = [4, 2, 1, 3]
        if (count > a.size()) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        count++;

        int rev = Integer.MAX_VALUE, rot;

        if (parentOP == OP.ROT) rev = minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, count, OP.REV);

        rot = minimumOpsRec(rotate(a), b, count, OP.ROT);

        return Math.min(rev, rot);
    }

    // don't mutate input
    private static List<Integer> rotate(List<Integer> list) {
        var newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.rotate(newList, 1); // try using util methods as much as possible
        return newList;
    }

    // don't mutate input
    private static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> list) {
        var newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.reverse(newList); // try using util methods as much as possible
        return newList;
    }

    enum OP {
        REV,
        ROT
    }
}
```

And here if you want to find which transforms:

```java
import java.util.*;

class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var a = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
        var b = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 1, 4, 3));
        System.out.println(minimumOps(a, b));
    }

    public static Map.Entry<Integer, List<OP>> minimumOps(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        if (Objects.equals(a, b)) return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0, new ArrayList<>());

        var rev = minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, 1, OP.REV);
        var rot = minimumOpsRec(rotate(a), b, 1, OP.ROT);

        return rot.getKey() >= rev.getKey() ? rev : rot;
    }

    public static Map.Entry<Integer, List<OP>> minimumOpsRec(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b, int count, OP parent) {
        if (Objects.equals(a, b) || count > a.size())
            return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(count, new ArrayList<>(List.of(parent)));

        count++;
        
        Map.Entry<Integer, List<OP>> rev = null;
        Map.Entry<Integer, List<OP>> rot;
        
        if (parent == OP.ROT) rev = minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, count, OP.REV);
        
        rot = minimumOpsRec(rotate(a), b, count, OP.ROT);

        if (rev != null && rot.getKey() >= rev.getKey()) {
            rev.getValue().add(parent);
            return rev;
        }
        rot.getValue().add(parent);
        return rot;
    }

    // don't mutate input
    private static List<Integer> rotate(List<Integer> list) {
        var newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.rotate(newList, 1); // try using util methods as much as possible
        return newList;
    }

    // don't mutate input
    private static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> list) {
        var newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.reverse(newList); // try using util methods as much as possible
        return newList;
    }

    enum OP {
        REV,
        ROT
    }

}
```

Simplified version:

```java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var a = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
        var b = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 1, 4, 3));
        var output = minimumOps(a, b);
        if (output == Integer.MAX_VALUE) System.out.println("Can't be solved");
        else System.out.println("Min transforms: " + output);
    }

    public static int minimumOps(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        return minimumOpsRec(a, b, 0);
    }

    public static int minimumOpsRec(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b, int count) {
        if (Objects.equals(a, b)) return count;
        if (count > a.size()) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        count++;
        return Math.min(minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, count), minimumOpsRec(rotate(a), b, count));
    }

    private static List<Integer> rotate(List<Integer> list) {
        var newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.rotate(newList, 1);
        return newList;
    }

    private static List<Integer> reverse(List<Integer> list) {
        var newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        Collections.reverse(newList);
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, good luck

Comment: thank u vv much, but I would like to only use the list<Integer> that I'm provided with instead if maps, since then I'll have to do from scratch again. Is that possible?

Comment: heres the link to my new question where I've shown what I've done so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668387/how-can-i-find-how-many-times-functions-must-be-called-recursively-to-get-the-ri

Comment: if you can solve it using just the List<> that is provided, it would be greatly beneficial for me

Comment: @Droid, don't really get what you are trying to achieve. However, your implantation (in the referenced quation) doesn't seem to be logical because most of the time you don't have loops inside a recursive method (again, recursion itself is a loop). I think the provided solution in the answer is the way to go. You can modify it or whatever, but at the end of the day the general concept is the same. If you think that you don't understand recursion very well, start with simple examples and examine them very carefully.

Comment: can you please explain what this line does ----  *if (parentOP == OP.ROT) rev = minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, count, OP.REV);*

Comment: @Droid it's referring to the second tree that I've demonstrated, more specifically this line "we know that `reverse(reverse(list)) == list`...". For example, imagine this list `a=[1, 2, 3, 4]` now reverse the list twice. `reverse([1, 2, 3, 4]) = [4, 3, 2, 1]`, now reverse the result `reverse([4, 3, 2, 1]) = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, if you've noticed we have ended up with the same list that we've started with. So what the line really does is skipping this double reversing to safe time. However, you still can remove the if statement (and the whole OP thing) and end up this same result.

Comment: So I could simply just say "rev = minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, count, OP.REV);" and deleting the if statement wouldn't change anything right?

Comment: also can you suggest some sites for me to learn recursion, I'm a bit puzzled by how it works

Comment: @Droid the answer is now updated with a simplified version. You can practice recursion [here](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?topicSlugs=recursion&difficulty=EASY&page=1).

Comment: Thank you, also one more question, how does *return Math.min(minimumOpsRec(reverse(a), b, count), minimumOpsRec(rotate(a), b, count));* cover the case where both reverse() and rotate() are used, since based on my understanding, minimum would return the smallest out of EITHER the recursive rotate() or reverse() functions. how does it cover the case if BOTH rotate() and reverse(0 are used?